# Проблема с корутной

Tags: c#, unity3d

Уже ранее показывал этот код:

```
private IEnumerator OnL() {
    WaitForSeconds secE = new WaitForSeconds(0.01f),
                   secF = new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);
    while (h.e < this.e) {
        h.e += 0.2f;
        yield return secE;
    }
    while (h.f < this.f) {
        h.f += 0.2f;
        yield return secF;
    }
}
```

Происходит проблема на мобиле, выражается она тем, что она медленно начинает работать.
На компе, она буквально за пол секунды увеличивает значения.
А на мобиле, это секунд за 5, а то и больше, почему так происходит?
Данный метод активируется через метод:

```
public void OnS() {
    StartCoroutine(OnL());
}
```

А этот метод запускается по кнопке, ведь ничего сложного нет в этих методах, а почему такая огромная разница и как с этим бороться?
Возможно `FPS` проседает, но тут `Update` не используется, все срабатывает в циклах.
Как быть в такой ситуации и как это исправить?

Знатоки выручайте!
Уже 3 день не могу разобраться никак.

Comment: может  быть   на  компьютере   фунцкия   OnS   вызывается    несколько  раз,  нет  ??   просто   если  запустить   эту  сопрограмму   несколько  раз,  то   действительно  может    быстрее    пройти   сопрограмму.   когда    у  тебя  вызывается  OnS  ??

Comment: ну  либо  разница   между   h.e  и  this.e    на  компьютере    меньше,   и  поэтому   h.e  доходит  до  this.e  быстрее .   Какие  значения  у  тебя   в  этих  переменных  ??  может  быть    они   по  разному   инициализируются   на   компьютере   и   на   мобильном  телефоне  ??  Как  ты  присваиваешь  им  значения  ??

Comment: @Slavik, `когда у тебя вызывается OnS` - читайте вопрос внимательнее, а не закрытыми глазами. `Какие значения у тебя в этих переменных ??` - `this.e` = `18`, а `this.f` = `0.5`. `может быть они по разному инициализируются на компьютере и на мобильном телефоне ??`, дак если вы не знаете, что тогда такой бред пишете? `Как ты присваиваешь им значения ??`. Оо, нынче появился новый способ присваивания свойст класса? `:facepalm:` .  `private readonly int e = 18;
    private readonly float f = 0.5f;` Тоже самое и с теми что увеличиваются, только без `readonly`.

Comment: Что  за  кнопка? Может  быть    кнопка  на  клавиатуре,  может   быть   это кнопка  пользовательского   интерфейса? По  какому  именно  событию  запускается  метод?

Comment: @Slavik, обычная `UI` кнопка по которой кликают - мышкой, пальцем, просто посмотрят на нее... (только что это дает? Причем тут это вообще).